Inline Images Displayed as Attachments in iOS Mail App
I'm using Django to send HTML emails that include an inline logo image using the cid (Content-ID) method. The email is sent and rendered correctly in most email clients, but in the iOS Mail app, the logo appears also as an attachment at the bottom of the email and than inline within the HTML content. Additionally, the attachment icon is visible in the email list view.
Here is the code I’m using (Written in Python/Django):
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

# Sending the email
email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    subject=subject,
    body=html_content,
    from_email=from_address,
    to=to_email
)
email.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")

# Adding logo as inline attachment
with open(self._get_logo(domain), 'rb') as logo_file:
    logo = MIMEImage(logo_file.read())
    logo.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline')
    logo.add_header('Content-ID', '<logo>')  # Important: Set CID here
    email.attach(logo)

In the HTML content, I reference the image like this:
<img src="cid:logo" alt="Logo">

Is there a known workaround or a specific way to ensure that inline images are displayed correctly in the iOS Mail app without showing them as attachments? Any advice on handling this issue within Django or HTML emails in general would be greatly appreciated.

You normally host the image on a public server and then reference it with a URL in the href, i.e. <img href="https://image.server.com/image">
Content-ID works by attaching the image, that's what it is. It increases the size of the email because it's an attachment (although if it's just a logo that's not an issue).
I'm surprised you have found it working on "most" email clients, and even iPhones. Does it work on Gmail webmail? It is generally accepted in the email community that this is not a foolproof method.

Yes it works everywhere. Even in gmail. More an more companies are doing this and from a user perspective it is very nice to see the logo instead of the white box with a red cross in it. I analysed how the company are avoiding this problem on iOS and the only difference I currently see is that they use "multipart/related". Any idea how to send the html part as "multipart/related"?

There are examples on other SO questions with multipart examples
